# Trying to build a tvOS form that works like Apples settings

Tags: animation, tvos

my AppleTV app needs a small form to setup a server link. I decided that the best approach was to make it look and feel like Apple's tvOS settings pages. The initial setup to create a split view with the form on the right was no problem, but I've run into some look and feel issues with entering data.

The example I'm using as a base is the settings: *AirPlay - Conference Room Display - Custom Message* field. This is a text field. Selecting it and tapping the remote activates a text entry field, displaying a keyboard with a title and message.

I have partially achieved the same look and feel by creating a table view with a static cell, which I then add a hidden `UITextField` to and use the following code for the cell class:

```
@interface CRXTVOSTextFeildCell: UITableViewCell<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *value;
@end

@implementation CRXTVOSTextFieldCell {
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *_textField;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    _textField.delegate = self;
    _textField.text = value;
}

-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder {
    return [_textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.value = textField.text;
}

@end
```

This is mostly working however I have a problem I've not been able to solve.

When the keyboard activates, it just fades in the full screen over the top of the table view. With Apple's preferences, the keyboard does a zoom in effect. I've tried all sorts of code from stack over flow and other places, but so far nothing seems to work in terms of changing the keyboard animation.

So my question is how can I make the tvOS keyboard zoom in when it appears like Apple does in it's preferences?